# Slot representing the key in Association?

Tags: associations, slot

Is there a slot representation of the Key in an Association?
For instance, I would like to do same transformation with an Association:

```
Plot[#2, {x, 0, 10}, PlotLabel -> #1] & @@@ {{"A", Sin[x]}, {"B", Sin[2 x]}, {"C", Sin[3 x]}}
```

What if I have:

```
<|"A" -> Sin[x], "B" -> Sin[2 x], "C" -> Sin[3 x]|>
```

I can of course do this in multiple ways, but prefer the simple and elegant way...

Comment: `KeyValueMap[
 Plot[#2, {x, 0, 10}, PlotLabel -> #1] &,
 <|"A" -> Sin[x], "B" -> Sin[2 x], "C" -> Sin[3 x]|>
 
 ]`

Comment: Thank you! Maybe its just, but I would like a KeyValueApply...

Comment: You mean the name could be misleading? Right, that's probably arguable.